# Redirect and URL Mask all non-existing/existing subdomains to homepage

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-masking

A website example.com has one subdomain *a.example.com*. The point here is I want to redirect all existing and non existing subdomain (ex- *b.example.com*) to **example.com** without changing URL(URL MASK). To explain it more further, when a user enters b.example.com he must see example.com on his screen but URL must not change from b.example.com --> example.com. I think its possible from .htaccess file but I failed to achieve it.

Do I need to configure virtual host. Since I only have access to .htacces, I wish I can get it done

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two things configured correctly:

1. A DNS entry with wildcard (*.example.com -> your server IP)
2. A virtual host with wildcard alias (`ServerAlias *.example.com`)

Then there is nothing to do in .htaccess. .htaccess alone can't do what you want. And please note also that this could be SEO-toxic (duplicate content), but it depends on your use case.

As you do not have access to virutal hosts config, may be you could go with subfolders instead of subdomains.